# Spring batch restart resumes the old execution id but processes all records instead of just the unprocessed records

Tags: spring-batch

I am currently using ListItemReader and trying to restart my spring batch. However, the step execution context read count and write count is set to 0. In the database i can see the read, write and commit count to be correctly set for the previous job run that failed. However, on restarting everything is being set to 0. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

`ListItemReader` is *not* an `ItemStream`. It does not save any restart data in the execution context. That's why it will always re-read items from the in-memory list on each execution.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for your reply. Can you please suggest (or share any code snippet) how I can make it restartable.

Comment: To make it restarable, you need to implement `ItemStream`. You can try to use the index of items in the list as restart data. The index can be saved in the execution context in the `update` method and restored from the context on restart in the `open` method.